# Unterminated array at character 37

Tags: android, android-studio, json

Im building an android app that gets some info from a JSONObject.
Hoever, this specific object throws an error:

```
Unterminated array at character 37 of {"name":"Pollin", "tags":["Sandwich", "Papas Fritas", "Tortilla"]}
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks

EDIT: I figured it was because of the spaces.  Now I'm wondering how to include spaces so that JSONObject does not throw an exception.

Comment: There is a problem with your Json object. If you have access to your Json object, try and any online Json parser. Copy and paste your Json Object and see if it can validate.

Comment: What parser are you usng? may well have a strictness attribute